# Set different max/min- height, width on multiple elements with jqueryUI resizable

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jQuery-UI resizable on three elements, like this:

```
$("#element1, #element2, #element3").resizable();
```

All good and well.. BUT I need to set max/min- height, width. I can't see way in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-maxHeight) nor in the [example](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min) to give the elements different (as in unique for each element selected) values on these:

```
  maxHeight:
  maxWidth: 
  minHeight: 
  minWidth:
```

That means that I will have to call the .resizable() one time for each element.... That doesn't feel optimal. Like this:

```
$("#element1").resizable({
    maxHeight:
    maxWidth: 
    minHeight: 
    minWidth: 
});

$("#element2").resizable({
    maxHeight:
    maxWidth: 
    minHeight: 
    minWidth: 
});

$("#element3").resizable({
    maxHeight:
    maxWidth: 
    minHeight: 
    minWidth: 
});
```

What I would have liked is something like this:

```
$("#element1, #element2, #element3").resizable({
    [
        maxHeight: 111, //#element1   
        maxWidth: 111, 
        minHeight: 111, 
        minWidth: 111,
    ],
    [
        maxHeight: 222, //#element2
        maxWidth: 222, 
        minHeight: 222, 
        minWidth: 222,
    ],
    [
        maxHeight: 333, //#element3
        maxWidth: 333,
        minHeight: 333,
        minWidth: 333,
    ],

});
```

Is this somehow doable?

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve it this way inside of the resizable `start` event.

Give all of your resizable elements a common class.

You can use a switch statement, still quite a lot to write.

```
$('.widget').resizable({
  start: function(event,ui) {
    var hasId = ui.element.attr('id');

    switch(hasId ){
      case '#element1':
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxHeight', 111);
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxWidth', 111);
        break;
      case '#element2':
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxHeight', 222);
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxWidth', 222);
        break;
      case '#element3':
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxHeight', 333);
        ui.element.resizable('option','maxWidth', 333);
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Or, you could use data attributes to set the maxHeight and maxWidth like so:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.widget').resizable({
    start: function(event,ui) {
      var minH = $(this).attr('data-minH');
      var maxH = $(this).attr('data-maxH');
      var minW = $(this).attr('data-minW');
      var maxW = $(this).attr('data-maxW');
      
      $(this).resizable('option', 'minHeight', minH);
      $(this).resizable('option', 'maxHeight', maxH);
      $(this).resizable('option', 'minWidth', minW);
      $(this).resizable('option', 'maxWidth', maxW);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.widget {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="element1" class="widget" data-minH="100" data-maxH="100" data-minW="100" data-maxW="100"></div>
<div id="element2" class="widget" data-minH="100" data-maxH="200" data-minW="100" data-maxW="200"></div>
<div id="element3" class="widget" data-minH="100" data-maxH="300" data-minW="100" data-maxW="300"></div>
```